# How to sort a List of Objects based on duplicate fields?

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I have the following Java POJO

```
public class Game  {

    public Game(){} 

    private String id;

    private String startDate = "";
}
```

How can I implement functionality that will determine **duplicate fields** within a list of Game objects?

For example when both Games have the same start date?

I have used `comparator` before but only when sorting objects, e.g. based on earliest date etc, but can it be used to sort duplicates?

Comment: comparator methods have convention of return -1, 0 and 1. If method returns 0, it means both objects are equal.

Comment: how on earth would you sort 'duplicates'? if they are equal, either order is 'sorted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> comparator ... can it be used to sort duplicates?

Yes. When `compareTo` returns 0, that groups all equal elements together.

> determine duplicate fields within a list of Game objects?

Make a `Comparator<Game>` that has a comparison condition of

```
if (game1.startDate.equals(game2.startDate)) return 0;
```

By the way, you may want to use some type of `LocalDateTime` object instead of strings. Then you can actually order dates/times

Comment: `Comparator.<Game>comparing(Game::getStartDate)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find "duplicate" entries, group elements and look for groups with size > 2.

In Java 8 that would be something like:

```
games
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Game::getStartDate))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(group -> group.size() > 1)
    .map(group -> group.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `startDate` is private, a comparator might have no access to this field. Well known method `equals()` could be overwritten but if you want to check object fo different criteria of equality, this won't suffice.

But you may implement a getter that will serve `startDate` to the comparator. Or you can impement method `boolean isSameDateAs(Game other)` that will return true for duplicate.